# ActiveMQ-STOMP dropping messages

Tags: python, machine-learning, activemq-classic, message-queue, stomp

I am using Stomp.py to connect to an ActiveMQ server, but not all messages are getting received.

I have started an ActiveMQ server with the stomp protocol on localhost:61613.
I have my own class in python that is a subclass of stomp.ConnectionListener.

```
class MyClass(stomp.ConnectionListener):
```

I connect to localhost:61613 with stomp upon initialization of my class and subscribe to a topic queue.

```
self.conn = stomp.Connection([(localhost, 61613)])
self.conn.set_listener('', self)
self.conn.connect('admin', 'admin', wait=True)
self.conn.subscribe(destination='/topic/test', id=1, ack='auto')
# infinite loop here is necessary to keep the program listening
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

In the on_message method inherited from stomp.ConnectionListener, I store all the messages I receive in 'input_data.csv', as well as pass the message I receive to a machine learning model for prediction (takes some time). I've removed the code details to focus on the issue.

```
def on_message(self, frame):
    inputList = frame.body.split(',')
    # I store the message in a csv, lets call it 'input_data.csv'
    self.storeInputData(inputList)
    # I pass the message in for the ML model to do some prediction, takes some time
    model.predict(inputList)
```

To send messages to the queue I have a separate file that will read a csv with the testing data and send it row by row.

```
conn = stomp.Connection([('localhost', 61613)])
conn.set_listener('', stomp.PrintingListener())
conn.connect('admin', 'admin', wait=True)
conn.subscribe(destination='/topic/test', id=1, ack='auto')
with open('testing_data.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        conn.send('/topic/test', ','.join(row))
```

I check sent vs received messages by comparing the contents of 'testing_data.csv' from which I send all my data, to the 'input_data.csv' which I am storing all the received messages in.

The result of comparing the two csvs is this. [(Deleted rows means rows that are missing in input_data.csv) The input_data.csv has the first ~40,000 rows of the testing_data.csv, then is missing the next ~160,000 rows, has the next ~1,000 rows, misses ~70,000 rows, has the next ~5,000 rows, misses ~18,000 rows, has the last ~1000 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNVXd.png)

This result caused me to wonder if either ActiveMQ or Stomp had some sort of message per second limit, or some sort of expiration for the messages that are waiting in the queue.

Because I send the lines in my testing_data.csv very quickly, I decided to test out using time.sleep to wait 0.01 seconds between sending lines in my csv. I figured a rate of 100 messages per second wouldn't be too much.

```
conn = stomp.Connection([('localhost', 61613)])
conn.set_listener('', stomp.PrintingListener())
conn.connect('admin', 'admin', wait=True)
conn.subscribe(destination='/topic/test', id=1, ack='auto')
with open('testing_data.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        conn.send('/topic/test', ','.join(row))
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

The new result was this. [The input_data.csv has the first ~68,000 rows of the testing_data.csv, then repeats the cycle of missing the next ~4,000 rows and having the next ~3,000 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXbn5.png)

Does the fact that I'm limiting the messages per second to about 100 and there are still issues mean that there is some sort of expiration for the messages waiting in the queue while the machine learning model is making predictions? As far as I know, Stomp uses multiple threads to handle received messages, so is there some type of thread limit?
How would I further diagnose this issue and fix it?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a Topic the QoS is inherently lossy, if the receiver is not up when the sender is sending the messages are dropped immediately.  Also the broker configuration matters here as well as you could have a [Pending Message Limit Strategy](https://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling) enabled which is discarding older messages as the topic backlog gets to high due to a slow consumer.

Comment: Thank you! Disabling the pending message limit strategy worked for me.